# What is the spatial complexity of Map<Integer, List<String>>?

Tags: java, dictionary, big-o

I trying to calculate the space complexity of my code in Java, and I am using just maps and list, but I am not sure it is `O(n^2)` or `O(n)` and why? .

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();;
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>() ;
```

Usually a data structure inside another data structure is generally O(n^2) right?

thanks

Comment: Generally, HashMap is O(1), not O(n), but it depends on many things, mainly on the implementation of the hash code. There are already  various complete hash algoritams that you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to define what *n* is, then it is relatively easy to determine the space complexity. I will define *n* as the number of strings which are placed in the HashMap. I will also assume that the minimum load factor in the hash table is 0.5. Let *I* be the size of an Integer, *S* be the maximum size of a string, *H* be the space used by a single slot of the hash table, and *L* be the maximum length of a list in the hash table.

Then, for a minimally filled hash table there will be *n* / *L* occupied slots, each with at most *SL* space plus *I* for the key allocated. The hash table itself will take *2Hn* / *L* space---the 2 is due to the load factor. Thus, the total space will be *[(SL + I + 2H) / L] n*, which is just *O(n)*.

Comment: Actually I am reading a large text file, and I am storing the words in the list, thanks for answering